# Calculate the streaks of visit of users limited to 7

Tags: sql, rank

I am trying to calculate the consecutive visits a user makes on an app. I used the rank function to determine the streaks maintained by each user. However, my requirement is that the streaks should not exceed 7.

For instance, if a user visits the app for 9 consecutive days. He will have 2 different streaks: one with count 7 and the other with 2.

Using MaxCompute. It's similar to MySQL.

I have the following table named visitors_data:

```
user_id visit_date
murtaza 01-01-2021
john    01-01-2021
murtaza 02-01-2021
murtaza 03-01-2021
murtaza 04-01-2021
john    01-01-2021
murtaza 05-01-2021
murtaza 06-01-2021
john    02-01-2021
john    03-01-2021
murtaza 07-01-2021
murtaza 08-01-2021
murtaza 09-01-2021
john    20-01-2021
john    21-01-2021
```

Output should look like this:

```
user_id streak
murtaza 7
murtaza 2
john    3
john    2
```

I was able to get the streaks by the following query, but I could not limit the streaks to 7.

```
WITH groups AS (
    SELECT  user_id,
            RANK() OVER (ORDER BY user_id, visit_date) AS RANK,
            visit_date,
            DATEADD(visit_date, -RANK() OVER (ORDER BY user_id, visit_date), 'dd') AS date_group
    FROM visitors_data
    ORDER BY user_id, visit_date)

SELECT 
    user_id,
    COUNT(*) AS streak
FROM  groups 
GROUP BY 
    user_id,
    date_group
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Max Compute. It's similar to MySQL

Comment: The function DATEADD() that you use in your code uses SQL Server syntax, so obviously MaxCompute is not like MySql.

Comment: There are some differences obviously, but I've personally found it to be closest to mysql. Nevertheless, I know if I understand the logic, I'll be able to recreate it in Max Compute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My thinking ran along similar lines to forpas':

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) streak
FROM 
(
   SELECT 
      user_id, streak, 
      FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, streak ORDER BY visit_date)-1)/7) substreak
   FROM 
   (
      SELECT 
         user_id, visit_date,
         SUM(runtot) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY visit_date) streak
      FROM (
         SELECT 
            user_id, visit_date, 
            CASE WHEN DATE_ADD(visit_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY) = LAG(visit_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY visit_date) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as runtot
         FROM visitors_data
         GROUP BY user_id, visit_date
      ) x
   ) y
) z
GROUP BY user_id, streak, substreak
```

As an explanation of how this works; a usual trick for counting runs of successive records is to use LAG to examine the record before and if there is only e.g. one day difference then put a 0, otherwise put a 1. This then means the first record of a consecutive run is 1, and the rest are 0, so the column ends up looking like ​1,0,0,0,1,0... SUM OVER ORDER BY sums this in a "running total" fashion. This effectively means it forms a counter that ticks up every time the start of a run is encountered so a run of 4 days followed by a gap then a run of 3 days looks like 1,1,1,1,2,2,2 etc and it forms a "streak ID number".

If this is then fed into a row numbering that partitions by the streak ID number, it establishes an incrementing counter that restarts every time the streak ID changes. If we sub 1 off this so it runs from 0 instead of 1 then we can divide it by 7 to get a "sub streak ID" for our 9-long streak that is 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1 (and so on. A streak of 25 would have 7 zeroes, 7 ones, 7 twos, and 4 threes)

All that remains then is to group by the user, the streak ID, the substreakID and count the result

Before the final group and count the data looks like:

[image]

Which should give some idea of how it all works

Comment: is it possible to add start and end date in the above query? I also want the most recent streak from substreaks. Meaning recent streak with bool flag.. if flag=false, it strarts as new streak and reset previous continuous streak

Answer (score 1):

You could break them up after the fact.  For instance, if you never have more than 21:

```
SELECT user_id, LEAST(streak, 7)
FROM (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS streak
      FROM groups 
      GROUP BY user_id, date_group
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) gu JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 2 as n UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
     ) n
     ON streak >= n * 7
ORDER BY LEAST(streak, 7);
```

If you have an indeterminate number range for the longest streak, you can do something similar with a recursive CTE>

Comment: Since I'll be using the monthly active user data, the streaks could and do exceed 21

Comment: The problem is that when I use the union all select 4, I only get 4 7-day streaks of a user that visited the app 30 days in a row. The 2 day streak is missing.

Comment: @MurtazaKamal . . . Off-by-1 error.  I fixed the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1):

With a mix of window functions and aggregation:

```
SELECT user_id, COALESCE(NULLIF(MAX(counter) % 7, 0), 7) streak
FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, grp ORDER BY visit_date) counter
    FROM (
      SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY visit_date) grp
      FROM (
        SELECT *, COALESCE(DATE_ADD(visit_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY) <> 
                  LAG(visit_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY visit_date), 1) flag
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM visitors_data) t
      ) t
    ) t 
) t
GROUP BY user_id, grp, FLOOR((counter - 1) / 7)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02cfea75aa89a748332daca9b387395e).